# How would I detect when a user is speaking in a voice channel discord.JS v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I’ve been searching online for this for hours, and haven’t been able to find anything that is new.

I do know that the audio stuff is in a different package now though.

Comment: Join a voice channel [like so](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html). This returns a [`VoiceConnection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/stable/class/VoiceConnection), which has a `receiver` property ([`VoiceReceiver`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/stable/class/VoiceReceiver)). Use `VoiceReceiver.subscribe(userID)` to subscribe to when a user with `userID` is speaking. This returns an [`AudioReceiveStream`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/stable/class/AudioReceiveStream). Once you have the stream, you can pipe it to an MP3 file or such and do what you want with it

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late and that there's already an answer but here is some code using the libraries discord.js and @discordjs/voice

```
npm i discord.js
npm i @discordjs/voice
```

```js
//requirements
const discord = require('discord.js')
const voice = require('@discordjs/voice')
const client = new discord.Client({intents: Object.values(discord.Intents.FLAGS)}) //Object.values(discord.Intents.FLAGS) is used to get every intents 
//on ready
client.on('ready', () => {
    //log username
    console.log(client.user.username)
})
//
var connection
//when a message is sent
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    //split message by args
    const args = message.content.split(' ')
    if(args[0] == "join") {
        //check if the message author is in a voice channel
        if(message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id) == null) return 
        //create a new voice connection (join a voice channel)
        connection = voice.joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).voice.channel.id, //the id of the channel to join (we're using the author voice channel)
            guildId: message.guild.id, //guild id (using the guild where the message has been sent)
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator //voice adapter creator
        })
        connection.receiver.speaking.on('start', (userId) => {
            //actions here
            console.log(userId)
        })
    }
    if(args[0] == "destroy") {
        if(connection == undefined) return message.channel.send('the bot isn\'t in a voice channel')
        //leave
        connection.destroy()
        connection = undefined
    }
})
client.login("token here")
```